# How to sort images on click using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dom

I have a table of 8 images that I need to sort alphabetically when I click on any of the images. The image that has been clicked goes to the first position in the first row of the table. The next position in the first row will be the image whose name is alphabetically right after the name of the first one and so on for the other images. The images are stored in an array called 'flowers'.

Here is what I have so far:

```
      // Sort Images
  let imgClick = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < imgClick.length; i++){
  imgClick.addEventListener("click", flowers.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1)))
};
```

The images don't get sorted when I click them.

Comment: Do the images have `name` attribute set? Notice, that `name` is a custom attribute for images. It's also not clear how do you know the array is not sorted? Are you expecting the images on the page to change their position?

Comment: @Teemu Yes I have a function that sets the name attribute for all images. I check the console to see if the array is sorted but it is not. I also want the images on the page to change their position.

Comment: I [can't reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/nphszmxL/) with the provided code, please add more details, rather a [mre]. Notice, that a sorting function should return a tristate (-1, 0, 1), not just -1 or 1.

Comment: The result of `flowers.sort` is being set to the click, it is not being called on click

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will sort a list of already existing images in place. The images need to be in a common parent container (`div#pics`). By clicking on any of the images this one will be placed at the first position.

```js
let imgs = [...document.querySelectorAll('#pics img')].sort((a,b)=>a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
    div=document.querySelector("div");
div.onclick=ev=>{
  if(ev.target.tagName!=="IMG") return;
  let i=imgs.indexOf(ev.target);
  imgs.slice(i).concat(imgs.slice(0,i)).forEach(img=>div.appendChild(img))
}
```

```css
img {margin:8px}
```

```html
<div id="pics">
<img src="pic1" name="c" alt="c"><img src="pic1" name="b" alt="b"><img src="pic1" name="a" alt="a"><img src="pic1" name="d" alt="d">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will give you an idea of how to implement that.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("flowers");
const flowers = [
  "rose",
  "peruvian lily",
  "chrysanthemum",
  "orchid",
  "tulip",
  "carnation",
  "hyacinth"
 ].sort();
 
 
function PlaceFlowers(flowers) {
  container.innerHTML = "";
  
   for(let flower of flowers) {
    container.innerHTML += `<button id="${flower}" onClick='sortFlowers(event)'>${flower}</button>`;
 }
}

PlaceFlowers(flowers);
 
function sortFlowers(event) {
  const el = event.target.id;
  const indOfEl = flowers.indexOf(el);
  PlaceFlowers([...flowers.slice(indOfEl), ...flowers.slice(0, indOfEl)]);
}
```

```html
<div id="flowers"></div>
```